# Response Header is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http-headers, jax-rs

Im calling a web service from Angular

```
return $http.post(url_base 'appointment/export/', filter)
  .then(handleSuccessHeaders, handleError('Error exporting file')); 

function handleSuccessHeaders(data, status, headers, config) {
    var res = {data:data, status:status, headers:headers,config:config}; 
    return res;
}
```

The services is for exporting an Excel file, if I use a client I can't downloand the file (I see the headers), but I need the headers since there is important information I need but is always undefined.

This is the service definition

```
@POST
    @Path("/export/")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
    public Response exportInformation(AppointmentFilterDTO filter) {

        String pathFile = "/home/files/test.xlsx"

            File file = new File(pathFile);
            if (file.exists()) {
                java.nio.file.Path path = file.toPath();
                return Response
                        .ok(new OutputStreamImplementation(path), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                        .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename =" + path.getFileName().toString())
                        .header("Content-Length", file.length())
                        .header("success", true)
                        .header("contentType", "application/vnd.ms-excel")
                        .build();
            } else {
                return Response.ok()
                        .header("success", false)
                        .build();
            }
    }
```

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if I'm missing something, I tried with getting the headers from data.headers() and it doesn't work either

Comment: traditionally, the function called by `.then` receives a single argument - do you know for a fact that `$http.post`'s (whatever that is) `.then` is called with 4 arguments?

Comment: you are using .then like it was .success `.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {` - I believe you could do `function handleSuccessHeaders({data, status, headers, config})` instead

Comment: As I said I tried with one argument, but when I tried to do something like response.headers.name,it says is undefined

Comment: `As I said I tried with one argument` - where? anyway, console.log the one argument, what does it look like - also try console.log(arguments.length) in that function, see how many arguments are being passed

Comment: {data: "symbols with data", status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ}

Comment: so, the one argument has `headers` .. you must be doing something wrong when you use a single argument - did you try `function handleSuccessHeaders({data, status, headers, config})` - assuming your browser is modern, of course

Comment: You said you tried it with one argument and that didn't work so you broke the code further by splitting it erroneously into four arguments. Then you gave us **double broken code**. I really don't  understand why people do that. Just give us single broken code and explain the issue.

Comment: The `headers` property of the response object is a **Header getter function.** The function needs to be invoked: `response.headers()`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after trying so many things I realized the error wasnt on the Angular side, I just had to exposed the custom headers I wanted to be visible when consuming the web service with Access-Control-Expose-Headers, since I'm using CORS, I just had to add them in the conf class like this:

```
corsFilter.setExposedHeaders("header1,header2,header3");
```

Also I used one argument in the service invocation.